# ReCaptcha Google data-callback with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I have implemented google Captcha in my angularjsApp.

I have this HTML

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{key}}" data-callback="enableBtn()"></div>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
$scope.enableBtn = function(){
   $scope.captchaSigned = true;
};
$scope.key = "xyz";
```

But not working and in my console return :

```
ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: enableBtn()
```

How can I make a data-callback with `Angularjs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved with this library https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha

Answer (score 3):

In your html put :

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{key}}" data-callback="enableBtn"></div>
```

And in your controller, put :

```
var enableBtn = function(){
   $scope.captchaSigned = true;
};
$scope.key = "xyz";
window.enableBtn = enableBtn;
```

This should work as it will bind the function in controller.

Comment: I have tried before put "()" after "enableBtn" but it doesn't work. I have resolved with https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha

Answer (score 1):

instead of `$scope.enableBtn = function(){` define your function as `window.enableBtn = function(){`

Ensure you use `data-callback="enableBtn"` and NOT `data-callback="enableBtn()"`

Answer (score 0):

In Controller :

```
window.wrongCaptchaResponse = true;
window.recaptchaResponse = function(key) {
    window.wrongCaptchaResponse = false;
};
```

In HTML page:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid || wrongCaptchaResponse">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize recaptcha in your angular controller. eg.

inside your controller add this on a button click or initialize or timeout if you need it on page load. :

```js
function showRecaptcha(){
 if(typeof grecaptcha !='undefined'){
  grecaptcha.render('register-recaptcha', {
           'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
           'callback' : recaptchaCallback,
         });
 }
}

function recaptchaCallback(resp){
 console.log(11,resp);
}
```

```html
<div  id="register-recaptcha"></div>
```